# Get data from other table based on column with concatenated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

`category` with columns:

```
id    name
1     business
2     sports
...
```

`article` with columns:

```
id   title    categories
1    abc      1|2|3
2    xyz      1|2
```

I know there should be a separate table for article categories but I was given this.

Is it possible to write a query that returns:

```
id    title     category_names
1     xyz       business,sports
```

I thought of splitting the string in `article` -> `categories` column, then use **in query** to extract `name` from `category` table but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Consider this useful reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your data model.  But, you can do this in SQL Server:

```
select a.*, s.names
from article a cross apply
     (select string_agg(c.name, ',') as names
      from string_split(a.categories, '|') ss join
           category c
           on try_convert(int, ss.value) = c.id
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21d0f0dd3af8b3f76c456a5bcc71ecdd) is a db<>fiddle.

Presumably, you already know the shortcomings of this data model:

- SQL Server has poor string handling functionality.
- Numbers should be stored as numbers not strings.
- Foreign key references should be properly declared.
- Such queries cannot make use of indexes and partitions.
- If you really want to store multiple values in a field, SQL Server offers both JSON and XML.  **Strings are not the right approach.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Gordon, I'm getting following error: `Aggregates on the right side of an APPLY cannot reference columns from the left side.`

Comment: @Ashutosh . . . It works fine.  I added a db<>fiddle.